# Не подключается скрипт на страницу Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

На странице index.ejs не вызывется скрипт script.js.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Вот собстна сам скрипт script.js:

```
alert(123);
```

На  сколько я понимаю, как только страница открылась, сразу должен выскочить этот алерт, но его нет...Все файлы находятся на одном уровне, в одной папке.

Вот код файла server.js:

```
 var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var server = new http.Server();

var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log('Express server listening on port' + app.get('port'));
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url == '/') {
        res.render("./index.ejs");
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Я запускаю сервер, открываю localhost:3000, там появляется мой index.ejs, но вот скрипт, который подключён к нему, не срабатывает....

Comment: а в консоли браузера ошибок нет?
Добавьте эту строчку:

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei Сработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй `src="./script.js"`. Путь неправильный

Comment: Нет. И так не срабатывает. И даже просто src="script.js" не рсабатывает...